# С# очистка экрана при Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#

Возникла такая проблема. В данном отрывке, когда выполняется условие `else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)` экран консоли очищается и программа ожидает ввод данных, после ввода экран обновляется и всё работает дальше как надо. Почему экран очищается? Как это исправить?

```
while (true)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
            Console.WriteLine(phrase);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 22);
            Console.WriteLine("Введите команду: ");
            while (r.yo != r.yt) //правая стена
            {
                outext(st, r.xo, r.yo);
                r.yo -= 1;
            }
            r.yo = yo;
            while (r.xo != r.xt) // нижняя стена
            {
                outext(st, r.xo, r.yo);
                r.xo -= 1;
            }
            r.xo = xo;
            while (r.yo != r.yt) // левая стена
            {
                outext(st, r.xt, r.yo);
                r.yo -= 1;
            }
            r.yo = yo;
            while (r.xo != r.xt) // верхняя стена
            {
                outext(st, r.xo, r.yt);
                r.xo -= 1;
            }
            outext(st, r.xo, r.yt);
            r.xo -= 1; // последний "кирпичик"
            r.xo = xo;
            key = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
            {
                a.move(0, -1);
                if (a.y <= r.yt)
                {
                    a.move(0, 1);
                }
                outext(sy, a.x, a.y);
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                a.move(0, 1);
                if (a.y >= r.yo)
                {
                    a.move(0, -1);
                }
                outext(sy, a.x, a.y);
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
            {
                a.move(-1, 0);
                if (a.x <= r.xt)
                {
                    a.move(1, 0);
                }
                outext(sy, a.x, a.y);
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
            {
                a.move(1, 0);
                if (a.x >= r.xo)
                {
                    a.move(-1, 0);
                }
                outext(sy, a.x, a.y);
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 22);
                c = Console.ReadLine();
                if (c == "Осмотреться")
                {
                    phrase = "Вы находитесь в комнате";
                }
                outext(sy, a.x, a.y);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `Почему экран очищается?` ... `Console.Clear();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед тем как задавать вопрос на стекОверфлоу тебе нужно было отдебажится и пройтись самому построчно по коду нажимая F11 и ты сам бы увидел в чем проблема, даже, не читая кода.

давай ты попробуешь это сделать и увидишь что все дело в `Console.Clear();`

Comment: Хм... То есть после else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) начинается новая итерация? Это как-то странно.

Comment: давай ты пройдешься дебагом построчно по коду) Это реально очень часто решает проблему, даже, если ты не подозреваешь где именно проблема.

Comment: Не является ответом, подобного рода сообщениям место в комментариях.

Comment: И без дебага можно поискать глазами `Console.Clear` :)

Comment: @NewView я сначала это и написал... А потом решил что лучше если сам найдет через дебаг и подправил ответ)

Comment: :) это верно, кстаи, развивает мышление такой подход у тс :)

Comment: @aa_talanin хоть ответом и не является, зато такой ответ в 100 раз полезнее чем буквальный ответ в чем конкретно проблема. Окроме того, сделав что я написал -- он решит проблему. Так что спорно является ли ответом или нет)

Comment: Для сообщества не несет никакой пользы. Кто-нибудь будет гуглить про очистку консоли, попадет сюда и увидит ответ "Пройдитесь отладчиком". Если бы в ответе был бы хотя бы намек на причастность метода Console.Clear, то ответ был бы хоть сколько-нибудь информативным, но сейчас это просто "Автор лентяй, пусть разбирается сам".

Comment: @Andrew `такой ответ в 100 раз полезнее` - тут будет правильней `такой комментарий`. Спору нет, полезно автора научить работать с отладкой... но это можно делать и в комментариях под вопросом, а после того, как он найдет проблему - пусть сам (или вы) и ответит. Но текущий ответ не как не относится к поставленному вопросу, что неверно по правилам сайта!

Comment: @aa_talanin для сообщества и конкретно даный вопрос не несет никакой пользы) Но эт такое) И еще раз, я изначально ответил в чем проблема... А потом исправил ответ так, что бы мой ответ был более полезным ТСу. Что, по моему мнению, значительно важнее в даном конкретном случае чем дословное соблюдение правил.